# encrypt a file automagically in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption

How do i encrypt a file in C#? i would like to use a db (like sqlite) and use it normally except have the file encrypted and have my user enter his password before having access to the database.

Comment: I think you might be confused here, what would be the file that is encrypted or are you talking about the connection to the database?  Also, are you wanting to use a table in the db to authenticate a user or the db's authentication?

Comment: I think he wants to use a sqlite3 database and encrypt that file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

- Use DPApi (Data Protection API), which is supplied in the ProtectedData (System.Security.Cryptography class), and use an entrophy based on a password
- Use SQL Compact Edition, which has this built in
- Generate a key based on a password and encrypt/decrypt the file with that
- Use Encrypted File System, so the OS will take care of encryption on the disk. (Consumer editions of Windows don't have this though.)

And there are probably more ways to do this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you use EFS remember to back up the keys!

Comment: As with any security application, encrypted data without a key is like a locked door without a key. You may be able to get in, but it is going to take a lot of time :)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) (it's an inprocess database server like SQLite) allows you to encrypt the file [without writing any additional code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171966.aspx#).

To change the password, use the [Engine.Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171752.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteConnection.SetPassword

[SQLite ADO.NET provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

I think you also have to set the Password= parameter in the connection string.